# protractor count() expectation fails unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have the following code which filters elements containing text:

```
    var myspan = searchChoices.filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            //console.log('index text:'  +text);
            return text === 'Consultant 110';
        });
    });

    expect(myspan).not.toBe(null);
    myspan.count().then(function (x) {
        console.log('count:'+x);
    });

    expect(myspan.count()).toBe(1); // this succeeds
    expect(myspan.count()===1).toBe(true); // <---This fails
```

The strange thing is that the expectation at line before the last line succeeds but the last one fails.  What is the reason ?

Comment: [`count()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) returns a promise, not an integer. `expect()` knows how to handle the promise but `count() === 1` will always fail

Comment: Yeah but isn't expect supposed to resolve all promises before evaluating?

Comment: Yes, but that is a boolean you're passing to it, not a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that everything webdriver related in Protractor *returns a promise* - an object that would be put on a [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) that would be resolved later in the queue of promises. The actual value is not immediately available.

Now, `expect()` has a special behavior - in Protractor (actually in `jasminewd2`) it is *patched to understand promise*s - it would resolve a promise before making the expectation. This is why `expect(myspan.count()).toBe(1)` is working in your case. And, `myspan.count()===1` would always be `false` - since `myspan.count()` itself is a promise and it is always not equal to `1`.

FYI, if you want to have the `=== 1` check, you could manually resolve the promise:

```
myspan.count().then(function (actualCountValue) {
    expect(actualCountValue === 1).toBe(true);
});
```